# NodeJS: MySQL sometimes raises ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, error-handling

I'm currently developing an application using NodeJS.

However, often the server throws this error, and I can't interact with mysql.

```
 [Error: read ETIMEDOUT]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true }
{ [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false }
```

Does someone have a solution to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just reconnecting (assuming the problem is that the connection is lost)?

Comment: This is actually two separate errors.  

For the second, this is normal behavior, as it will occur when you try to query on a connection once a fatal error has occurred.

You may be calling a method on your connection like query sometime earlier in your code and are accidentally not checking the returned error. Another possibility is you are checking the errors, but not checking if err.fatal is true and discarding the connection.

Comment: Hey, you might have made a connection with the sql in some other file which you must have required in the app.js and would have executed a query in app.js or any other file which also you have included. Now before making connection or after getting an error in the connection object you are still making the query.

Comment: @mscdex : Yes i can be reconnect because I close the server

Comment: @Gary:  Maybe but why a fatal error is throw with a basic request ?

Comment: @Aditya_Anand : Not I have only one connection (at the running of the server)

Comment: It looks like the query is taking too long.  You may want to increase your request timeout.  The option is documented in the API specs.

Comment: @NapstersDesmars :  try to log the connection object. It must have a error.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I assume that you can work with your database perfectly but this error happens often after a given time of that connection being up...

Supposing you are using `node-mysql`
Source : https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#error-handling
Your error terminates your connection to the database :

> **err.fatal:** Boolean, indicating if this error is terminal to the connection object. 
>   If the error is not from a MySQL protocol operation, this property will not be defined.
>
> Note: 'error' events are special in node. If they occur without an
>   attached listener, a stack trace is printed and your process is
>   killed.
>
> **tl;dr:** This module does not want you to deal with silent failures. You
>   should always provide callbacks to your method calls. If you want to
>   ignore this advice and suppress unhandled errors, you can do this:

```
    // I am Chuck Norris:
connection.on('error', function() {});
```

From this you could check connection status and perform a reconnect if needed.

---

You could also try to connect manually to your mysql service and change request timeout :

```
wait_timeout” : the amount of seconds during inactivity that MySQL will wait before it will close a connection on a non-interactive connection in seconds.
```

http://www.serveridol.com/2012/04/13/mysql-interactive_timeout-vs-wait_timeout/
https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use mysql2 over mysql npm pakcage. it will solve your problem.

full explanation [here](https://www.koffeewithkode.com/how-to-solve-error-read-etimedout-in-node-js/)