# Connection is "sometimes" undefined when pooling mysql connections

Tags: mysql, express

I'm using expressjs+mysql for my project. I sometimes get `connection` is undefined while using the connection object in a query. But sometimes it works and the query executes.

The code:

```
    var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
     host     : '192.168.2.2',
     user     : 'testmysql',
     password : 'test123',
     database : 'tollsystem',
     debug    :  false
});
```

I get the error here while using the pooled object:

```
    app.get('/getClientList',function(req,res){
    var data={
        "error":1,
        "clients":""
    };
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    connection.query("select * from mstrclient",function(err,rows,fields){

        if(rows.length !=0){
            res.json(rows);
        }else{
            data["error"]=1;
            data["clients"]="no details found";
            res.json(data);
        }
        connection.release();
    })
  });
});
```

The error:

```
        connection.query("select * from mstrclient",function(err,rows,fields){
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\server.js:415:15
    at Handshake.onConnect (D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\node
_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:58:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\n
ode_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:85:24)
    at D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\node_modules\mysql\lib\pr
otocol\Protocol.js:399:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\node_modules\mysql\lib\pr
otocol\Protocol.js:398:13
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

The error at `getConnection`:

```
    { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

Comment: Use `console.log(err)` before the `.query` call.

Comment: @hjpotter92. i've posted the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJs mysql error ETIMEDOUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003770/nodejs-mysql-error-etimedout)

Comment: @hjpotter92. can you explain in an answer how to handle the timeout and reconnect?