# Connection timed out when using connection pooling

Tags: mysql, express

I get the following error when I get a connection object from a connection pool. It works sometimes but sometimes I get an error and the `connection` is undefined. I don't think I am supposed to get a connection timeout error because I'm using connection pool and in a connection pool you already have a few connections and you're not creating a new connection.

Can someone tell me how to handle this error and connect again.

The error at `getConnection`

```
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

The code:

```
    var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
     host     : '192.168.2.2',
     user     : 'testmysql',
     password : 'test123',
     database : 'tollsystem',
     debug    :  false
});
```

I get the error here while using the pooled object:

```
    app.get('/getClientList',function(req,res){
    var data={
        "error":1,
        "clients":""
    };
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    console.log(err);
    connection.query("select * from mstrclient",function(err,rows,fields){

        if(rows.length !=0){
            res.json(rows);
        }else{
            data["error"]=1;
            data["clients"]="no details found";
            res.json(data);
        }
        connection.release();
    })
  });
});
```

The error:

```
        connection.query("select * from mstrclient",function(err,rows,fields){
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\server.js:415:15
    at Handshake.onConnect (D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\node
_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:58:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\n
ode_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:85:24)
    at D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\node_modules\mysql\lib\pr
otocol\Protocol.js:399:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at D:\abhilash\Projects\Toll main aHosted\TollMain\node_modules\mysql\lib\pr
otocol\Protocol.js:398:13
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Comment: How is this question different [from your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543640/connection-is-sometimes-undefined-when-pooling-mysql-connections)?

Comment: @robertklep. i want to know how to handle the timeout and reconnect. should i use recursive function to try until I get a connection

Comment: @robertklep. please help me mister